# How to iteratively modify membership functions using command line functions of fuzzy logic toolbox?

Tags: matlab, fuzzy-logic, fuzzy

Can someone give me an idea on how to iteratively modify the parameters of a chosen membership function using for loops for the tipping example problem in mathworks.

Basically without setting parameters to the membership function I want to iterate then over different parameter and test each one to get the optimal parameter.

what should be the range of values that I iterate through?
How do I test which parameter gives me the optimal/best output?

I will be using command line functions of fuzzy logic toolbox by modifying the .m files of them.

Comment: If you parameterize all your membership functions with a limited number of parameters, you can do a parameter optimization using e.g. [`fminsearch`](https://nl.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fminsearch.html?searchHighlight=fminsearch&s_tid=doc_srchtitle). You have to define a metric (cost function) to see what parameter set will perform best.

Comment: @rinkert, what do you mean by a limited set of parameters.  Also to define a cost function and get the optimized parameters don't I need  a dataset to check which parameter gives the correct result. Lastly how do I define the parameters for the membership functions under each input like for good bad and moderate under service input. How will it know which membership function relates to how good the satisfaction level. Let me know if I'm not clear about my question.